# Clicking '+add' makes addRow dialog fire multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am building a new application using `dataTables`. The tables are called when a menu item is clicked. When I open one of the tables (`customers`) for the first time, then click the `+add` button the dialog fires as expected (Which is to say it fires only once).

If I open the `customers` table a second time and click the `+add` button, the dialog fires twice. The same happens with the users table. (The same thing happens when using the `users` table.) Any following call raises the total number of the dialogs that will be created.

How can I set the dialog to fire only once for each newly added table?

(I am working on a localhost with MAMP. If a working example is needed I can upload the application to the server.)

I am using:

- jquery 1.7.1
- DataTables 1.9.0
- jquery.dataTables.editable 2.3.3
- jeditable 1.6.2

Yesterday I was busy till 4:00 am. I really can not find any solution.
It likes I am the only one facing this problem.
6 hours on Google couldn't also give me any answer.

Please I need some help.

The dialogbox HTML:

```
<div class="add_delete_toolbar" />

<!-- Custom form for adding new records -->
<form id="formAddNewUser" action="#" title="Add new user">

    <input type="text" name="id" id="id"  rel="0" readonly/>
    <br /> <br />
    <label for="title">Title</label><br />
    <select name="title" id="title" class="required input_field" rel="1">
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="Mister">Mister</option>
    <option value="Madam">Madam</option>
    </select>
    <br /> <br />
    <label for="vnaam">Name</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="vnaam" id="vnaam" class="required input_field" rel="2" />
    <br /> <br />
    <label for="anaam">Surname</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="anaam" id="anaam" class="required input_field" rel="3" />
    <br /> <br />
    <label for="adres">Username</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input_field" rel="4" />
    <br /> <br />
    <label for="postcode">Password</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="input_field" rel="5" />
    <br /> <br />
    <label for="plaats">Email address</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input_field" rel="6" />
    <br /> <br />
</form>
```

the table jquery script:

```
<script>
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
oTable2= $('#gebruikers').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "../ajx/gebr/ss_users.php",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

}).makeEditable({
    sAddNewRowFormId: "formAddNewUser",
    sAddNewRowButtonId: "btnAddNewUser",
    sAddNewRowOkButtonId: "btnAddNewUserOk",
            sAddNewRowCancelButtonId: "btnAddNewUserCancel",

sUpdateURL: function(value, settings)
                                {
            //return(value); //Simulation of server-side response using a callback function

                                },
            sAddURL: "../ajx/gebr/add_user.php",
            sAddHttpMethod: "GET",
            sDeleteHttpMethod: "GET",
    sDeleteURL: "../ajx/gebr/remove_user.php",
    sUpdateURL: "../ajx/gebr/update_user.php",
            "aoColumns": [
                    {   

                                                    },
                                                    {
                      cssclass: "required" ,
          indicator: 'Saving title...',
                      tooltip: 'Click to select a title',
                      loadtext: 'loading...',
                      type: 'select',
                      onblur: 'cancel',
                      data: "{'':'Please select...', 'Mister':'Mister','Madam':'Madam'}",
          submit:'SAVE'
                    },
                                                    {   
                                                      cssclass: "required" ,
          indicator: 'Saving name...',
                      tooltip: 'Click to edit name',
          type: 'text',
          onblur: 'cancel',
          loadtext: 'loading...',
                      submit:'SAVE'
                                                    },
                                                                                   {                        
        cssclass: "required" ,
            indicator: 'Saving name...',
                    tooltip: 'Click to edit name',
        type: 'text',
        onblur: 'cancel',
        loadtext: 'loading...',
                    submit:'SAVE'
                                                    },
                    {
        indicator: 'Saving username...',
                    tooltip: 'Click to edit username',
        type: 'text',
            onblur: 'cancel',
        loadtext: 'loading...',
                    submit:'SAVE'
                    },
                    {
                    indicator: 'Saving password...',
                    tooltip: 'Click to edit password',
        type: 'text',
        onblur: 'cancel',
        loadtext: 'loading...',
                    submit:'SAVE'
                    },
                                                    {
                    indicator: 'Saving email...',
                    tooltip: 'Click to edit email',
        type: 'text',
        onblur: 'cancel',
        loadtext: 'loading...',
                    submit:'SAVE'
                    }

    ],
        oAddNewRowButtonOptions: {  label: "Add...",
            icons: {primary:'ui-icon-plus'} 
    },
        oDeleteRowButtonOptions: {  label: "Remove", 
           icons: {primary:'ui-icon-trash'}
    },

        oAddNewRowFormOptions: { title: 'Add a new user',
                                                        show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",
                            modal: true
    }   ,
                                              sAddDeleteToolbarSelector: ".dataTables_length"   
});
```

});

The menu calling the table:

```
$('#new_user').click( function(evt){

           //prevent loading the data if already loaded
    if ($(document).find('#gebruikers').length == 0) { 
        //remove tabs active class
         $(".tabs_links ul li").removeClass("active");

             $("#response").load("pages/tmp_users.php");

    }
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You forgot to post relevant code in question

Comment: post an example of your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the bindings have been created multiple times. Before recreating a new instance of the datatable, destroy the old one. For example:

```
// where datatable is the global variable you have used to contain the datatable
if (datatable != null) datatable.fnDestroy();
```

There may be a more performant way of doing this, but try this first.

Comment: I agree with you. I tried to follow your advise but when I use 'datatable.destroy()' I can not open any table anymore.